How to associate a product to a discount in shopify graph ql?
I am currently building a Shopify admin UI extension block to display discounts and update them. I want to update a discount by adding a product to it
I expect to have a GraphQL query that associates a product with a discount.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide your code so we can help you.

Here is the documentation you're looking for https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/selling-strategies/discounts/getting-started
